# Powershell script not updating after saves

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a Powershell script that I'm working on in Powershell ISE and I'm trying to run it as I go along to make sure that the changes work. When I make a change, I save it, run "Import-Module Start-Applications" to bring the most recent version in, and then run "Start-Applications". When I do this, I get error messages for code that I had removed, indicating that perhaps it's not updating as I thought it would. Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `-Force` parameter of `Import-Module` to reimport already loaded modules.

Comment: This, and other good reasons, is why you should restart ISE sessions when testing. Clean slate.

Comment: @Matt , is there a particular way to do that other than just closing the window? I would imagine a best practice would be a bit smoother than that.

Comment: I only said when _testing_. I would think the best practice is to run from clean slate as that is what others would be doing if they were to use your code. To save myself the effort of restarting sessions I use things like `Remove-Variable` so that my variables don't persist their types and data.